# How to omit opacity changes from jQuery show()

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to use the jQuery `show(700)` function, but I do not want any opacity changes.  The element in question has a background PNG image with alpha transparency, and the opacity change causes strange black borders around the background image during the animation.  How can I omit opactiy animation from the `show()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the animate function and simply vary the width and height.  Here's a plugin that will do a reveal.

```
jQuery.fn.extend( {
    reveal: function() {
       return this.each( function() {
           var $this = $(this);
           $this.animate( { width: "show", height: "show" } );
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found it.  Search for the `genFx` function in jQuery.  You see it loops through arrays of styles and returns an object of the right styles, which eventually gets passed to the `animate` function internally.  Just remove "opacity" from the array!

This also might work for you...

```
.animate({ width: "show" });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's *show slowly* (show with a duration) does a slidedown and a fadein simultaneously. If all you want is the slidedown, just use the slidedown.

```
jQuery("#someElement").slideDown(700);
```

Not much more to say about that.

Comment: I think the function name needs to be camelCase.

Comment: Also, it doesn't just slide-down and fade-in, it also expands the width.

Comment: Yeah, camel case, I updated my answer. And I forgot that show(milliseconds) does a fadein, a slidedown _and_ and slide "out". In that case @tvanfosson's answer looks best.

Comment: `slideDown` only animates the height, I primarily would like to animate the width.  My answer is working, and so is tvanfosson's.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You made my day, Although not directly related to the main question, I was trying to accomplish a slide down with animate and found your slidedown() answer...!! Awesome ..!!